# jQuery, Assign td text to a variable and post it

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, html-table

I am relatively new to JavaScript and have a problem I hope your can help

What I am trying to do is this

```
$("tr:not(:first-child)").each(function(){
                            var sitename = $("this" + "td:nth-child(1)").text();
                            var type= $("this" + "td:nth-child(2)").text();
                            var address= $("this" + "td:nth-child(3)").text();
                            var city= $("this" + "td:nth-child(4)").text();
                            var lat= $("this" + "td:nth-child(5)").text();
                            var long= $("this" + "td:nth-child(6)").text();
                            var ftime= $("this" + "td:nth-child(7)").text();
                            $.post('./watchdog.php',{ oadata: sitename});
                    }).end().remove();
```

I am selecting the "tr" in a a table except the first one which contains "th". Then I am just stripping the td and assigning the text value to variable. In the end I am posting this data to a PHP script that basically inserts this in a MySQL DB. the problem is i keep getting NULL value in the database.

Here is my Table as generated in the HTML

```
Site Name   Type    Address City    Lat Long    Fault Time
ISB056  Spur    Opposite Plot No. 435, Sector I-10/4    Islamabad   73.04393    33.64677    12:02 PM
ISB078  Spur    SEECS NUST H-12 Islamabad   Islamabad   72.990044   33.64246    12:02 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$("this" + "td:nth-child(1)").text()
```

generates the selector `thistd:nth-child(1)` which does not make sense at all. I think you want:

```
$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text()
```

But easier would be to just take an array with e.g.

```
var data = $(this).children('td').map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
           }).get();
```

and then send the data like

```
$.post('./watchdog.php',{ sitename: data[0], type: data[1],...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You musn't use `'this'` but `this` so remove your quotes.

You also should use classes.

```
<tr class="site">
   <td class="sitename">...</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

That will make your code easier to read and to debug:

```
$("tr.site").each(function(){
    var sitename = $(".sitename",this)
})
```